# Extracting Lotus Notes NSF files under Linux

Tags: java, python, linux, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to extract NSF Lotus Notes files under linux. are there any opensource tools without the need of installing Lotus Note server ?

I do not have any experience with lotus notes my only task is to extract everything from NSF archive.

What i have found over web only said to install Domino server and use it via MAPI or COM which is not my option , i need to run under linux and i will only get multiple NSF files no server access.

Is the file structure is documented ? any documents available ? i cant find any NSF format specifications yet .

Any implementation of command line tools that works under Linux without Domino Installation or any lib / api that works without Domino will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't extract data from Lotus Notes without at least having the Lotus Notes client installed.

There are a number of ways to extract data from Notes.  You can write Java or LotusScript agents to export to file formats.  You can access Lotus Notes via the [Lotus Notes SQL driver](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/products/notesdomino/notessql/) and use SQL queries or MS Access to extract data.  There is an [Export to Excel](http://partialclass.blogspot.com/2009/02/export-to-excel-20-for-lotus-notes.html) database you can setup to extract to Excel.  And more.  All of them require the Notes Client (and the associated DLLs) to get at the data within, however.

Comment: THanks a lot for the info. So is lotus notes client free or have to buy domino server just to get client? Is it available for Linux ? if i script it commandline would be ok.

Comment: Good questions.  Since you don't need the server, just the client, you ought to be able to download a copy of the client for free, but you'll have to contact IBM about that.  If the NSF's require a login, which they most likely do, you'll need to have an ID certified on a Notes domain to gain access to the database.  That's something to discuss with whomever managed these databases prior to you.

Comment: The Domino-Designer is free to use - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/dominodesigner/

Comment: But LDD dont run on linux . so i can get Linux client for free? I have to email to IBM about it?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but you will need to consider using Windows, because..

Not for Linux -- but for Windows only, IBM allows a free download of Lotus Domino Designer (ie, LDD) -- which includes the client software also, along with several other Lotus Notes software (but not the Domino Server software, itself -- which you do not need, for your task)...
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/dominodesigner

This "LDD" download works great, on my "Windows 7 Home Premium" edition.

Your same NSF files will work fine, on a Windows machine -- with this LDD installed.

As a 15-year expert with Lotus Notes -- I suggest, you get some good coaching help, to fully understand and best tackle your specific task.

Also, here is a vital intro -- http://www.nsftools.com/misc/WhatIsNotes.htm

Comment: The project is an Ediscovery project. What i need to do is to extract data from Lotus note NSF files and extract emails , files , attachments iside NFS files. Core project is already written in python and runs on Linux. Parse most file formats including PST , Office Files ,etc.

Comment: Thats make using windows no longer possible. No problem about buying Lotus Notes but wants only client For linux.